# Find the smallest enclosing shape in python with a given amount of corners

Tags: python, polygon, bounding-box, shapely

Say you have two polygons (yellow and orange) representing two observations of the same building. It is likely the building has been modified between the observations.
How can I generate the smallest possible bounding shape (blue) that encloses both the underlying shapes, and has the same amount of corners as the input polygon with the fewest amount of corners?

[image: Polygons combinations]

The solution needs to be applicable to buildings of all shapes and sizes, but the specific illustrated problem showcases the issue well.

I have looked at using Alpha-shape and Convex hull, but could not produce the desired result.

Comment: What is the format of the polygons?

Comment: There is an algorithm for the minimum bounding rectangle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms. For an arbitrary bounding polygon, it might be a very difficult problem.

Comment: You can check out `arcpy` library and its [`MinimumBoundingGeometry` method](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm)

Comment: @Sala I'm a little confused about what you mean, but I've been using the Shapely library for my testing. The polygons are currently 2D, looking to see if we can make it also work in 3D at a later stage.